# parent object specific layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a rails app with a model consisting of items that belong to companies.

There are multiple users for this system and I want any user who logs in and looks for a specific item (belonging to a company) to see the company logo and letter head etc. as background.

i.e. each item knows his layout via the company parent object association, item belongs_to company

What do you suggest is the best and most elegant approach for modeling this in rails?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How customizable do you want the layouts?

At the high end, I suggest using the [Liquid template library](http://liquidmarkup.org/). It enables you and your integrators to *safely* change any aspect of the layout on a per company basis.

Flow: If the company has a liquid template stored in your system, then use it. Otherwise use a default template.

The other ways of doing things where you enable individual uploads of `logo,` `letter head,` plus css (to enable the right fonts for the company), etc etc, quickly becomes limiting.

Sooner rather than later, a company will insist on yet another change for their view and you'll need to add it. Instead, just make it all flexible by enabling per-company templates.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds interesting!

Comment: Glad to help. I use liquid templates in production and they work very well. By Googling for liquid, you can usually see a number of sw packages which also use Liquid.